# How to render an Apex pie chart with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to render a graph dynamically and what's happening is the graph flickers once, then nothing.

[Screen capture](https://i.gyazo.com/61680ddb0e499b2d6675f3300af9ebc5.mp4)

```
class ApexChartPie1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
 
      this.state = {
      
        series: []
           
          
      ,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 380,
            type: 'pie',
          },
          labels: ['LOST', 'WON'],
          responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
              chart: {
                width: 200
              },
              legend: {
                position: 'bottom'
              }
            }
          }]
        },
      
      
      };
    }

  
    async componentDidMount(){
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/designe/pieone")
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) =>{
        this.setState({series : data})
      
      })
    
    }
    render() {
      return (
        

  <div id="chart">
<ReactApexChart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="pie" width={380} />
</div>


      );
    }
  }


export default ApexChartPie1;
```

and the display code:

```
    import ApexChartPie1 from './ApexChartPie1'

</div>
<ApexChartPie1 > </ApexChartPie1> </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow content should be written in english. I took some time to translate your question's content, please make sure it describes the problem you're facing properly.

Comment: That said, you should really format the code in your question, in addition to providing a [mcve].